# GCF/LCM in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm extremely new to Haskell.

Is there a simple way to find the [GCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_factor) or LCM (Least Common Multiple) in Haskell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what the LCF is but the GCF is a Haskell favorite. Using the Euclidean Algroithm you can really get a sense of how Haskell works. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm There is a great explanation of how the algorithm is set up here [http://en.literateprograms.org/Euclidean_algorithm_(Haskell)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Euclidean_algorithm_%28Haskell%29) .

This type of recursion is common in Haskell and it shows how expressive the language can be.

```
gcd a 0 = a
gcd a b = gcd b (a `mod` b)
```

This uses pattern matching on the arguments to say the greatest common factor of any number and 0 is the first number. If the numbers are both non-zero, then look for the greatest common factor of the second and the first mod the second. Eventually this will reach 0 in the second argument. This will trigger the first pattern and return the first argument which is the answer.

[EDIT]

The function should actually be:

```
gcd a 0 = a
gcd a b = b `seq` gcd b (a `mod` b) where
```

This will force the evaluation of the previous recursion step's (a `mod` b) and will prevent a huge thunk being built in memory if, say, you are GCDing 1243235452 and 6095689787662. Seq forces the argument into its "Weak Head Normal Form" or evaluates the outer most data structure of the argument.

Comment: Should probably add in a `seq` here.

Comment: Absolutely. Though OP is new to Haskell it's as good time as any to learn this.

Comment: OP probably knows this, but `lcm a b = let g = gcd a b in (div a g) * b`

Comment: Tbh I think your explanation why you add `seq` isn't really a lot of a help for people new to FP or Haskell. For example: What's the _Weak Head Normal Form_? What's the _outer most data structure_? Out of what? Put like this it sounds like Haskell is doing something totally stupid, if you don't write that `seq`. And why is there a `where` with nothing following?

Comment: The `seq` is not needed, because `b` will already have been evaluated in order to find out if it's equal to 0.

Answer (score 16):

By GCF, do you mean the greatest common factor, or greatest common divisor? That's `gcd`, avaliable from the prelude, as is `lcm`, the least common multiple.

Answer (score 4):

`gcd` is imported in the prelude.  That means that you can use it whenever you want without going anything.  Erik Hinton shows a simple version of the Euclidean algorithm, if you are interested in implementing your own.  One thing though: `/` is used only for floating point division, use `div` and `mod` to find the quotient and remainder when you want to do "integer division."  The prelude also defines a `lcm` function for least common multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could also do

```
euclid(n,m) =
  if n == m then n
  else if n < m then euclid(n, m-n)
    else euclid(n-m, m)
```