# GCF in Haskell with elses

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Just started doing Haskell and I was given the task to do a basic GCF function similar to one for calculating a factorial.
This is what I came up with

```
ggt :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
ggt m n = if m < n then ggt n m
          else if n==0 then m
          else ggt n (m mod n)
```

I saw the responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922899/gcf-lcm-in-haskell) which, however, did in a completely different way than what I have been shown so far (I think it's called a guard pattern). My problem is that my code won't load and it says

```
 * Couldn't match expected type `(Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
                                    -> Integer -> Integer'
                  with actual type `Integer'
    * The function `m' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `Integer' has none
      In the second argument of `ggt', namely `(m mod n)'
      In the expression: ggt n (m mod n)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I don't understand why the types don't match (I have three Integers, two as an input, m and n, and one as a return) and, as a novice, I don't know what the second error really means.

I'd appreciate any and all help as well as all kind of explanations!

Cheers!

Comment: You want (mod m n) or ```m `mod` n```.

Comment: That is, `m \`mod\` n`.

Answer (score 1):

Non-operator function names must be enclosed in backticks to be used in infix position. That is,

```
ggt :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
ggt m n = if m < n then ggt n m
          else if n==0 then m 
          else ggt n (m `mod` n)
```

Otherwise, `m` is treated as the name of a function that takes the `mod` function as its first argument and `n` as its second. Such a function would have type `(Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer`, but `m :: Integer`, hence the error message.

A cleaner way to define this (nested `if` expresssions aren't the easiest to read) would involve one simple guard.

```
ggt :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
ggt m n | m < n = ggt n m
ggt m 0 = m
ggt m n = ggt n (m `mod` n)
```

or with a more involved guard instead of 3 separate pattern matches:

```
ggt :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
ggt m n | m < n     = ggt n m
        | n == 0    = m
        | otherwise = ggt n (m `mod` n)
```

Comment: Damn, really struggling with SO here. Anyway, what I wanted to say is that by doing that a new error pops up saying that the expected type still doesn't match with the actual type because ggt is applied to too many arguments. I agree that your method with the guard is clearly superior (which, if I understood correctly, basically works like an "if" on itself, right?) as I have implemented, but I'm still curious where my error lies!